# Token Authentication with Axios in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, token, http-token-authentication

I have created a login system in React with Axios, and it gives me a login token. I have saved this login token and response (LoginToken): **(Login.js)**

```
export default class Login extends Component {
 state = {
      redirect: false,
      redirectHR:false,
      email: "",
      password: "",
      isLogin: false,
      loggedIn: false,
      returnedEmail: "",
      returnedFirstName:"",
      returnedLastName:"",
      returnedCompanyName:"",
      returnedCompanyCode:" ",
      LoginToken:" ",
    }
        axios.post('/api/auth/login/', data, {headers:headers, withCredentials:true}).then(
          res => {
            if(res.data != null){
              console.log(res.data);
              this.setState({
                loggedIn: true,
                returnedEmail: res.data.email,
                returnedFirstName: res.data.first_name,
                returnedLastName: res.data.last_name,
                returnedCompanyName: res.data.company_name,
                returnedCompanyCode: res.data.company_code,
                LoginToken: res.data.token,  
              })
              console.log(this.state.LoginToken);
            }else{
              console.log("failed to log in");
            }
          }
        ).catch(error => {
          console.error(error.response);

        })
      }
....
```

Now I want to use this LoginToken as a header in another component **(AdditionalInfo.js)**
something like:

```
const headers = {
 'Authorization': 'Token your_Token'
}
export class AdditionalInfo extends Component {
  state = {
    locations:[],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/jobs/list-locations/',{headers:headers, withCredentials:true}).then(res=>{
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({locations:res.data})
    })
  }
```

instead of your_token, it should be the LoginToken I saved in the other component. I tried to use props but it didnt work and if I dont add this header I receive a 401 error and I can't receive info from the api. How should I import LoginToken in this file?

Comment: you can store the token on `localStorage` to use it across all the components.

Comment: you can also have a look at redux: https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use localStorage Web Api to store the token and use it anywhere.

Store it:-
`localStorage.setItem('LoginToken', res.data.token);`

Retrieve it:-
`let loginToken = localStorage.getItem('LoginToken')`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the good scenario will be if you are not using redux, storing it on the `localStorage` and getting it across different components.

```js
export default class Login extends Component {
 state = {
      redirect: false,
      redirectHR:false,
      email: "",
      password: "",
      isLogin: false,
      loggedIn: false,
      returnedEmail: "",
      returnedFirstName:"",
      returnedLastName:"",
      returnedCompanyName:"",
      returnedCompanyCode:" ",
      LoginToken:" ",
    }
        axios.post('/api/auth/login/', data, {headers:headers, withCredentials:true}).then(
          res => {
            if(res.data != null){
              console.log(res.data);
              // store the token in the localstorage
              window.localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
              this.setState({
                loggedIn: true,
                returnedEmail: res.data.email,
                returnedFirstName: res.data.first_name,
                returnedLastName: res.data.last_name,
                returnedCompanyName: res.data.company_name,
                returnedCompanyCode: res.data.company_code,
                LoginToken: res.data.token,  
              })
              console.log(this.state.LoginToken);
            }else{
              console.log("failed to log in");
            }
          }
        ).catch(error => {
          console.error(error.response);

        })
      }
....
```

getting token in other component

```js
const headers = {
 'Authorization': `Token window.localStorage.getItem("token")`
}
export class AdditionalInfo extends Component {
  state = {
    locations:[],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/jobs/list-locations/',{headers:headers, withCredentials:true}).then(res=>{
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({locations:res.data})
    })
  }
```

(or you should create a HOC to push the token to props.)

```js
export default withToken = (wrapperComponent) => {
   let token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
   if(!token){
       // push to login
       this.props.history.push('/login');
   }else{
       <wrapperComponent token={token}>
   }
}
```

and by using the hoc you can directly access token in the props of your component.